# VBA Run-Time-Error 91 at excel file compare code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a run-time error. The code is about to compare two excels.
I want to check all elements compared, and the different cell values would be colored in file2.

But every time i run it gets 91.

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim sh As Integer, ShName As String
    Dim F1_Workbook As Workbook, F2_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim iRow As Double, iCol As Double, iRow_Max As Double, iCol_Max As Double
    Dim File1_Path As String, File2_Path As String, F1_Data As String, F2_Data As String
    
    File1_Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2)
    File2_Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 2)
    iRow_Max = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(4, 2)
    iCol_Max = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 2)

    Set F2_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File2_Path)
    Set F1_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File1_Path)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, 2) = F1_Workbook.Sheets.Count 'At this point, the code say 91 rte
    
    For sh = 1 To F1_Workbook.Sheets.Count
        ShName = F1_Workbook.Sheets(sh).Name
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 1) = ShName
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 2) = "Identical Sheets"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        
        For iRow = 1 To iRow_Max
        For iCol = 1 To iCol_Max
            F1_Data = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol)
            F2_Data = F2_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol)
            
         
            If F1_Data <> F2_Data Then
                F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbRed
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(8 + sh, 2) = "Mismatch Found"
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(8 + sh, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next iCol
        Next iRow
    Next sh


End Sub
```

Comment: You've verified that `Set F1_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File1_Path)` Creates an appropriate path for the desired workbook?

Comment: If the workbook you are opening in `F1` it's too big, maybe it's just a time problem. Did you try `DoEvents` after opening workbooks? Did you make sure F1 is still open when that error arises?

Answer (score 0):

I find the misstake. The name off the two files was the same.